# How to dismiss the iPhone number pad?

Tags: iphone

Is there any simple method other than the one seen in

http://www.neoos.ch/news/46-development/54-uikeyboardtypenumberpad-and-the-missing-return-key

to dismiss a Number pad in iPhone??

This code for a single text Field seems a lot.!!

Comment: AFAIK this is the only current way of doing it - it's certainly what I do in a few projects. A real pain ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HI Finally from all the suggestions i Got it!!

Make your keyboard as Number Pad on Xib and put the following code in the .m file after connecting all the textFields..

```
-(void)touchesBegan NSSet *)touches withEvent UIEvent *)event
{
    [txt11 resignFirstResponder];
    [txt22 resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this by casting the background view to be a UIControl and then hook up a touch event to the controller's `[self.view endEditing:YES];`

[image]

You do this by changing the class of the base view in the xib to to be a `UIControl` instead of `UIView`

This means that the keyboard can be dismissed by touching the background.